# What does the 'cd' in a database column stand for?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database

i.e. foo_cd or bar_cd where they are ints in the database representing some "type" or "flavor". I know the letters c and d stand for something but I can't remember what.

In rails as_enum :foo_type, {:flavorA => 1, :flavorB => 2, :flavorC => 3} would make the DB col foo_type_cd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a `simple_enum` table suffix that [according to the author simply stands for `code`](https://github.com/lwe/simple_enum/issues/8#issuecomment-1538173).

Comment: omg u are right. what a terrible terrible abbreviation. sorry Lukas Westermann, love your gem :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard meaning for cd, but from your excerpt I would expect that it is short for code
(bar_code, foo_code). Best practice would be to avoid such abbreviations.

Comment: i think this is some standard someone came up with.  In rails as_enum :foo_type, {:flavorA => 1, :flavorB => 2, :flavorC => 3} would make the DB col foo_type_cd